# SharePoint Online Content Query Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I'm working on a query for my Content Query Web Part. The goal is to create a timeline similar to the Facebook timeline, the timeline shows the latest news and documents.

The latest news is retrieved from a list, the list is based on a content type 'news' with the columns 'Title(Single Text)', 'Sticky(Yes/No)', 'Content(Single Text)', 'Audience(Select)', 'Featured Image(Hyperlink or Image)'.

The latest documents are fetched from the site collection.

The search query(sorted on 'created' and 'RefinableString00(Managed property: ows_q_CHCS_Sticky)' I currently use is:

```
{searchTerms?} (contentclass:sts_listitem OR IsDocument:True) SPSiteUrl:https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite
```

The problem with the search is that it does sort on 'created' but not on the  'RefinableString00(Managed property: ows_q_CHCS_Sticky)'. It seems like the search query ignores the RefinableString00 when sorting.

Does anyone have experience with using sticky(yes/no choice) as sorting in a search query?

Comment: Did you mark it as sortable in Search schema?

Comment: Yes it is. Sortable is enabled by default if you use refinable managed properties in SP Online.